# Javascript calculate all values from HTML list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I'm developing budget diary web app and have problems with frontend, I have problems with updating budget .  Here is my code for Income:

**script.js**

```
var sum =0;
 $('#li-income-val').each(function() {
  sum += Number($(this).text());

});
$("#budget-income").text(sum)
```

**html code**

```
  <li id="li-icnome">
    <p class="dashboard__income__text">
        {{incom.title}}
    </p>
    <p id="li-income-val">{{incom.value}}</p>
    </p>
</li>
```

Is there any solutions ?

Comment: You've not really described the problem here, only told us that you have one. What is it? That being said, it looks like you're repeating the same `id` on all the `li` and `p` elements which is invalid; they *have* to be unique in the DOM. Change it to a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all Use class instead of id (id should be one)

**HTML**

```
<li class="li-icnome">
  <p class="dashboard__income__text">
    {{incom.title}}
  </p>
  <p class="li-income-val">{{incom.value}}</p>
</li>
```

**JS**

```
  var sum =0;
  $('.li-income-val').each(function() {
   sum = sum + parseInt($(this).text());
  });
  $("#budget-income").text(sum);
```